i having an error when i run mitm.py and i try install pyinontify with many ways but it not worked

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./mitmf.py", line 29, in 
import core.responder.settings as settings
File "/MITMf/core/responder/settings.py", line 24, in 
from core.configwatcher import ConfigWatcher
File "/MITMf/core/configwatcher.py", line 20, in 
import pyinotify
ImportError: No module named pyinotify


mitmproxy does not contain a file named mitmf.py. Therefore you have used the wrong mitmproxy tag. Also your question only contains an error message without the code that causes it which makes it unlikely to get an answer. Please learn how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
